# Access Passthrough Query from SQL Server 2005

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have created a passthrough query from an sql server database to display data into an access database. What i am wanting now is for this information to then update another table. which has other information on it other information on it imported from another passthrough query.

Comment: Have you considered linking views or tables? Is there a reason why you cannot run an update query as a pass-through query?

Comment: I think its more of a point I dont know how to. I have tried a simple update from the passthough query but wasnt sure if this would work as part if the passthough query. Would I just run an up date query seperatly or include the query in the passthrough query.

Comment: I imagine an update query should be enough, however, the best bet would be to post the update query here and see what people say. BTW using the At sign - @stackoverflow user name - will post a message to that user's SO inbox, which can sometimes get a quicker response.

Comment: Thanks for the info I will get onto that as soon as i can

Comment: @Remou Did you get an inbox notice from this comment?  I only see notices when comments are posted to an answer I submit, whether or not the commenter includes @HansUp

Comment: @HansUp Yes, I did, how about you?

Comment: @Remou Yes!  I could have sworn this wasn't working for me.  I'll just attribute my confusion to self-administered proctological examination.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of your passthroughs as read only queries.  You will not be able to do any record manipulation - only return data.

You would want a separate query that does your updates.  You may even have to write the resulting dataset from the passthrough to a temp table and use that in your update query.

In a simplified explanation of passthroughs, imagine I have two linked tables with 10000 records each and I link them for a query that returns 5 records.  Access needs to pull 20000 records (all from each table) across the network in order to compare them and give you 5 results.  In a passthrough, it does the comparison on the other end and only brings 5 records across.

Comment: Chances are very good that if you use the same SQL without the passthrough that Jet/ACE will also hand off the whole thing to the SQL Server for processing. Passthroughs are most convenient for SQL that Jet/ACE guesses wrong about (and doesn't pass off to the server), or for things that aren't possible within Access/Jet/ACE itself (such as executing SQL Server commands).